# Having some delays using python and tkinter for a real time GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, real-time

So I have a program in matlab that is sending numbers from 1 to 7 in random order, my python code has to light the respective word when receives the number (each word as a specific number related to it). This has to be as fast as it can, since this is a brain computer interface and the timings are extremly important.

What is happening is: when I'm simply printing the values I'm receiving from matlab no delays occur, I receive like this:

```
b'1\n'
b'7\n'
b'4\n'
b'2\n'
b'6\n'
b'3\n'
b'1\n'
b'5\n'
etc..
```

But when I include the GUI (i used Tkinter) part and print the values, it gives me:

```
b'1\n'
1
b'7\n'
7
b'4\n'
4
b'2\n'
2
b'6\n'
6
b'3\n'
3
b'1\n5\n1\n'
1
5
1
b'4\n3\n7\n'
4
3
7
b'6\n2\n5\n7\n2\n'
6
2
5
etc...
```

So when it starts receiving multiple numbers at a time it slows a lot the program.
It seems to me that either the tkinter is to slow or the loop is not right, but it is strange since it is only a few lines of code:

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import winsound
import socket
import sys

sounds = ["sim_esquerda_elev0_azim100.wav","nao_direita_elev0_azim100.wav",\
          "fome_esquerda_elev30_azim120.wav", "sede_direita_elev-40_azim148.wav",\
          "urinar_esquerda_elev-40_azim32.wav","ar_frente_elev0_azim0.wav",\
          "posicao_direita_elev30_azim60.wav"]

# TCP connection
try:
    so = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error as err:
    print ("socket creation failed with error %s" %(err))

#default port for socket
port = 2000

# default time out
#so.settimeout(1000000)

try:
    host_ip = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
except socket.gaierror:
    # this means could not resolve the host
    print ("there was an error resolving the host")
    sys.exit()

# connecting to the server
so.connect((host_ip,port))

# MATLAB INFORMATION FOR OFFLINE EXPERIMENT
Nepoch = 10  #nr de epochs por trial
Nwords = 7   #nr de palavras (SIM, NAO, FOME, SEDE, URINAR, AR, POSICAO)
SeqTrain = [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6] #sequencia offline de treino

# read the TCP sequence received
def sequencia():
    num = 0
    for i in range(0,999):
        s = so.recv(port) #+ b'\n' #since the sequence received is : 1\n 2\n 5\n etc
        print(s)
        for c in s.split():
            y = int(c)
            #print(c)
            #feedbak offline (for the user to know which are the words)
            if (num in (0, Nepoch*Nwords+1, Nepoch*Nwords*2+2, Nepoch*Nwords*3+3, Nepoch*Nwords*4+4, Nepoch*Nwords*5+5,\
                    Nepoch*Nwords*6+6)):
                labels1[y-1].configure(foreground="white")
                root.update()
            elif (num in (Nepoch*Nwords*7+7, Nepoch*Nwords*8+8, Nepoch*Nwords*9+9, Nepoch*Nwords*10+10,\
                     Nepoch*Nwords*11+11, Nepoch*Nwords*12+12, Nepoch*Nwords*13+13)):
                labels2[y-1].configure(foreground="white")
                root.update()
            else:
                labels[y-1].configure(background="green",foreground="red")
                root.update()
                winsound.PlaySound(sounds[y-1], winsound.SND_FILENAME)
                labels[y-1].configure(background="gray",foreground="white")
                root.update()
            num = num + 1
#window 
root = Tk()
root.title("Sequencia")
#root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)  #for fullscreen
#root.bind('<Escape>',lambda e: root.destroy()) #to get out of the full screen
root.state('zoomed')  #just zoomed not fullscreen
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
fm = Frame(root, width=w, height=h, bg="black")

#draw center lines
#wi = Canvas(fm, width=20, height=20, bg ="green", selectborderwidth=0)
#wi.create_line(0, 200, 150, 150, width=10, fill="blue")


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~LABELS FOR THE OFFLINE TEST TO SHOW UP IN THE SCREEN~~~~~~~~~~~~~
label_sim1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "SIM",  font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_nao1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "NÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_fome1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "FOME", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_sede1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "SEDE", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_urinar1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "URINAR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_ar1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "AR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_posicao1 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "POSIÇÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")

labels1 = [label_sim1,label_nao1,label_fome1,label_sede1,label_urinar1,label_ar1,label_posicao1]

label_sim2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "SIM",  font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_nao2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "NÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_fome2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "FOME", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_sede2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "SEDE", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_urinar2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "URINAR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_ar2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "AR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")
label_posicao2 = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="black", text = "POSIÇÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',15), fg="black")

labels2 = [label_sim2,label_nao2,label_fome2,label_sede2,label_urinar2,label_ar2,label_posicao2]

#posicionamento das palavras: [1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 4, 6] sim, fome, urinar, posição, nao, sede, ar, sim, fome, urinar, posição, nao, sede, ar
fm.pack()
label_sim1.place(relx=0.09, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_fome1.place(relx=0.14, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_urinar1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_posicao1.place(relx=0.27, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_nao1.place(relx=0.32, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_sede1.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_ar1.place(relx=0.42, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)

label_sim2.place(relx=0.46, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_fome2.place(relx=0.515, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_urinar2.place(relx=0.575, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_posicao2.place(relx=0.645, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_nao2.place(relx=0.695, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_sede2.place(relx=0.745, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)
label_ar2.place(relx=0.80, rely=0.07, anchor=CENTER)


#~~~~~~~~~~LABELS OF THE PARADIGM~~~~~~~~~~
label_sim = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "SIM",  font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_nao = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "NÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_fome = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "FOME", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_sede = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "SEDE", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_urinar = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "URINAR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_ar = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "AR", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")
label_posicao = Label(fm, width=10, height=1, bg="gray", text = "POSIÇÃO", font = ('TkDefaultFont',28), fg="white")

labels = [label_sim,label_nao,label_fome,label_sede,label_urinar,label_ar,label_posicao]

#ordem de sequencia (1 2 3 4 5 6 7): (SIM, NAO, FOME, SEDE, URINAR, AR, POSICAO)
#posicionamento das palavras: 
fm.pack()
label_ar.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.15, anchor=CENTER)
label_posicao.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
label_urinar.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
label_nao.place(relx=0.72, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)
label_sim.place(relx=0.28, rely=0.55, anchor=CENTER)
label_sede.place(relx=0.60, rely=0.77, anchor=CENTER)
label_fome.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.77, anchor=CENTER)

root.update()
sequencia()
```

Do you have any ideas on why this is happening? or advices to improve? I already tried separating the code with threads and it didn't work. Is it Tkinter a bad option? Or even python?
 Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for providing the X to your Y problem. Why do you need to generate the random numbers in MatLab, why not generate them with python?

Comment: It may be better structure to call root.update() at the bottom of the for loop in seqencia() instead of at the end of each if branch.

Comment: @jsarbour will try! thanks

Comment: _"the timings are extremly important."_ - if that is the case, tkinter is probably the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @BryanOakley do you know one that is good working with times? or all the python options are not desirable? thanks

Comment: @jsarbour I said random but it's not quite, in the matlab program we have all the pre-processing, classification, etc of the brain wave signals, and with that information we send the numbers for the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The calls to `update` is probably the main thing slowing down the loop. Each time you call it, it will attempt to service all pending events. You should consider calling it only once every few hundred milliseconds.

Also, playing a sound is going to be very slow, since you have to wait for the sound to play before the loop can continue.

Comment: i moved the update to only be called in the end of the loop in sequencia() and it didn't help. The thing is before we had a software called PRESENTATION that received the same codes in the same way (via TCP) for the auditory part, and never had these problem! worked prefectly

Comment: @FranciscaMachado: by "end of the loop" do you mean it's still inside the loop? That is still probably going to call it way more often than it needs to be called.